# bulk download from aws s3 on mac, i just want to choose my mac download location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i use the following command to download all file from aws
aws s3 sync s3://abc/folder .

all the file will be download to my directory of "user > myname"  on mac

Question
how could i change my download destination on my mac to "user > myname > newfolder" ?

Answer (score 0):

You just provide the path instead of using  `.`:

```
aws s3 sync s3://abc/folder /user/myname/newfolder
```

or

```
aws s3 sync s3://abc/folder ~/newfolder
```